# In oracle database how do we maintain same surrogate key (sequence value) on both tables simultaneously

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

In our data warehouse,  we have a requirement to load 2 tables which are at the same grain. Volume in both tables is exactly same. During the insert, i need to load same surrogate key (sequence) simultaneously. Are there any ways to achieve this?

Comment: Can you load one table first, and then - once you're done - "copy" rows from that table to the second table, simply reusing the key value? Or, depending on how you load data, if it is "one row into table 1, then one row into table 2" (which is a bad option, row-by-row is slow-by-slow, but table 1 could use sequence.nextval while table 2 would use sequence.currval (basically, the same value).

Comment: loading one table first and then loading the second is time consuming.We want to load the tables in parallel but maintain same key value. is there any way to achieve this using same sequence?

Comment: I don't think so. Once you use sequence.nextval, it is consumed and table 2 can't reuse it.

Comment: @Littlefoot Table 2 can use `sequence.currval` though

Comment: That's what I said 21 minutes ago, @Matthew :), but not - unless I'm wrong - in two bulk parallel loading sessions.

Comment: @Littlefoot sorry, missed that at the end of your 1st comment.

Comment: No problem at all, @Matthew

Comment: sequence.currval doesn't seem to be a possible option since its a set based processing not one row at a time.

Answer (score 3):

There are too many unknowns about your ETL process, so I apologize if this is way off.  It's too long for a comment though.

You can insert into multiple tables at the same time using the `INSERT ALL` command.  Like this:

```
create sequence matt_s;
create table etl1 ( id number, other_data VARCHAR2(30));
create table etl2 ( id number, other_data VARCHAR2(30));

insert all 
  into etl1 (id, other_data) values ( matt_s.nextval, other_data )
  into etl2 (id, other_data) values ( matt_s.nextval, other_data )
select /* dummy source data */ 
       to_char(rownum) other_data
from   dual src
connect by rownum <= 50;
```

Every row in the source query will be inserted into both tables and share common values for the `id` column.

Comment: I will try this method. Thank you!